# How to pop up for a window and ask user to input password in angular js

Tags: angularjs, razor, angular-ui

After satisfying a condition in index.cshtml, a window should popup asking for password as input and close it. I have seen buttons but not user input text in angular js. Does user input always depend on html or are there any standard libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at twitter bootstrap and their modal popup examples

Answer (score 0):

Use [Angular UI BootStrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) popup that would be Cool. Great angular binding support.

Steps to add.

1. You will need to add angular ui-bootstrap js and css
2. Then inside your app you need to add `ui-bootsrap` dependancy.

**JS**

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Hope this could help you. Thanks.

Comment: @Poonam E does it helped you?